# how to disable the word "check" from accessibility speech from CheckedTextView

Tags: android, accessibility

I am using a CheckedTextView within an adapter item. When the textview is checked and the accessibility is on, it reads out "checked ........." with other views' speech. Is it possible to make the CheckedTextView readout similar to normal TextView (just the text not the word "check" at the beginning) having Checked functionality.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The text is read according to the `onPopulateAccessibilityEventInternal`, you

can override.

```
    @Override
    public void onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        super.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(event);
        if (isChecked()) {
            event.getText().add(mContext.getString(R.string.radiobutton_selected));
        } else {
            event.getText().add(mContext.getString(R.string.radiobutton_not_selected));
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(info);
        info.setClassName(CheckedTextView.class.getName())
    }
```

But in android 30 the method is hidden. you can try to override the `getAccessibilityClassName` , let return TextView. it may  work.

```
public CharSequence getAccessibilityClassName() {
        return CheckedTextView.class.getName();
    }
```